# how to validate 3 div codes in one form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Inside a form with the id 'join_del', there are 3 div tags having a set of inputs.

I have prepared it such a manner that after button click in div "register1", it displays the div "register2". After button click in the div "register2", div "register3" will appear. The HTML code is:

```
<form id="join_del" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post" >
     <div id="register1" v-show="register1 == 1">
          Some Input Code Here
     </div>
     <div id="register2" v-show="register2 == 1">
          Some Input Code Here
     </div>
     <div id="register3" v-show="register3 == 1">
          Some Input Code Here
     </div>
</form>
```

The vue.js code is:

```
  data: {
            register1: 1,
            register2: 1,
            register3: 1,
            t_c1: 0,
        },
        secondForm(){
            this.register1=0;
            this.register2=1;
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        },
        thirdForm(){
            this.register1=0;
            this.register2=0;
            this.register3=1;
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        },
```

How can i validate and display the errors in "register1" before going to "register2" and so on.?

Comment: How is that jquery? It look like vue

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a computed property that prevents a 'Next' button. Something like:

```
<template>
<form>
  <div v-show="register">
    <input type="text" v-model="register1">
    <button :disabled="stepOneInvalid">Next Step</button>
  </div>
</form>
</template>

<script>
export {
  computed: {
    stepOneInvalid() {
      return this.register1.length == 0 // Or whatever your validation rules for each field are
    }
  }
}
</script>
```